# Split values of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list `lst = ['GS-1', 'GS-2', 'GS-3']`

How can I delete the "-" and every thing before it to get something like this? `['1, '2', '3']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your list is filled with strings you can use `.split()` method available to string and loop through the list.

List comprehension way

```
data = ['GS-1', 'GS-2', 'GS-3']
new = [elem.split("-")[-1] for elem in data]
print(new)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Normal Way

```
data = ['GS-1', 'GS-2', 'GS-3']
new = []
for elements in data:
     new.append(elements.split("-")[-1])
print(new)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

In a simple one line you can do something like this: 
 `numbers = [ item.split("-")[-1] for item in lst]`
This code iterate every items split it with "-" and takes anything after "-".